# How to differentiate between when TTS is stopped and TTS is done playing?

Tags: android, listener, android-5.0-lollipop, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

When TTS is done playing onDone(String utteranceId) is called from where I intend to call for the next sentence to play. But when I call tts.stop() again onDone(String utteranceId) gets called. So how will i be able to differentiate between the two so that i shouldn't call for the next sentence when the user stops TTS?

Answer (score 1):

`tts.stop()` as you say, is called by *you* - or rather, from your code. When you do this, set a Boolean value of `iStoppedManually` to true.

When the progress listener calls `onDone()` check the value of `iStoppedManually`. If it is true, you'll know *you* did it, otherwise, continue as normal.

Don't forget to reset `iStoppedManually` every time you find  it is set to true in `onDone()`